# iOS : Radio Button Programatically Without using any Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, radio-button

I have been working on creating custom ui controls and want to know how to add radio button to UIView programatically.

I only found one solution but it is for mac osx application control.
Image of required result is given as.
[image]

**LIMITATION**
Not want to use image.

Thanks.

Comment: Your attempts to achieve this yourself are...?

Comment: i use image for active and unactive button

Comment: so i have to keep track of unnecessary items.
is there any 3rd party library for that.

Comment: @jbutler483 will you please help me.

Comment: @AyanKhan will you please help me.

Comment: Use of 2 images is the simple & clean solution....Find the code https://github.com/t4ku/RadioButtonWithUIKit

Comment: @AyanKhan basically i need to colourised the  radio button that is not possible with image.

Comment: If you don't want to use images to indicate the selected and normal states of the button, then you can create your own button. There are actually a lot of ways achieving your goal. One of them would be creating your own subclass of `UIControl` with custom states as you define. For each state, you should draw different geometric figures depending on your requirements.

Comment: @FahriAzimov thanks for your help.
Now i get the idea.

Comment: @DanialHussain see my answer for radio button.

Comment: @DanialHussain Now see updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Radio button - Set corner radius and board color as below. Take three button in `ViewController.h` file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn3;

- (IBAction)ClickBtn1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ClickBtn2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ClickBtn3:(id)sender;
```

And in `ViewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.btn1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.btn1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    self.btn2.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.btn2.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    self.btn3.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.btn3.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    // default

    [self.btn1 setTitle:@"." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Button Action on click.

```
- (IBAction)ClickBtn1:(id)sender
{
    [self.btn1 setTitle:@"." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
- (IBAction)ClickBtn2:(id)sender
{
    [self.btn2 setTitle:@"." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
- (IBAction)ClickBtn3:(id)sender
{
    [self.btn3 setTitle:@"." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

in Your StoryBoard button View set as below height and Width `(20,20)` of the button. Take title name Dot (.) and its font size `System 44.0`and set Edge as below image.

[image]

Your Radio button is :

[image]

Comment: @DanialHussain i am update for three button with logic.